# file_get_contents of .txt file on google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to read the contents of a .txt file saved on google drive using PHP.  I can't seem to find a workaround for this.  It keeps displaying in google's wrapper.  I just want the plain old text.  I've tried:

```
      <?php
      $text = file_get_contents('https://drive.google.com/file/d/11dW2pOK-MXHGRzQhJWb37tlWMqazj8UZ/view');
      echo $text;
      ?>
```

Which displays a blank page and is not displaying any errors.  Any ideas on how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the URL to view the file, so you're basically opening the preview in HTML. To download the file directly, you need to use a different URL, which is

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={FILE_ID}
```

So your complete code would be

```
  <?php
      $text = file_get_contents('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11dW2pOK-MXHGRzQhJWb37tlWMqazj8UZ');
      echo $text;
  ?>
```